# Firefox SPNEGO Negotiate protocol - multiple connections?

Tags: firefox, kerberos, keep-alive, spnego, http-negotiate

I'm using gssapi/Kerberos authentication in my web application, and I want single sign on via the browser.

The problem is, Firefox sends an initial request to the server with no authentication, and receives a 401. But it includes a keep-alive header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

If the server respects this keep-alive request, and returns a WWW-Authenticate header, then Firefox behaves correctly and sends the local user's Kerberos credentials, and all is well.

But, if the server doesn't keep the connection alive, Firefox will not send another request with the credentials, even though the response has the WWW-Authenticate header.

This is a problem because I'm using Django, and Django doesn't support the keep-alive protocol.

Is there a way to make Firefox negotiate without the keep-alive? In [the RFC that defines the Negotiate extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559#page-4), there's nothing about requiring that the same connection be re-used.

Alternatively, is there a way to make Firefofx preemptively send the credentials on the first request? This is explicitly allowed in the RFC.

Answer (score -1):

That header is HTTP 1.0, wake up, fast-forward 15 years and your problems will go away. Firefox works very well with SPNEGO.